# Adding and Removing in pygame Groups

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game where if you kill one mob, two more spawn from certain coordinates on the screen. Here is what I have so far:

```
if Mob.hp == 0:
    Mob = MOB([50, 50])
    mobs.add(Mob)
    Mob.kill()
    Mob.image = ENEMY
```

`Mob` is the individual Mob and `mobs` is the group of Mobs. How can I get it so it removes the one mob killed, and replace it with two more? This need to repeat every time a Mob is killed

[UPDATE]

I have made a few changes to the code, listed here (Thank you @DominicKexel):

```
if Mob.hp == 0:
    Mob.kill()
    Mob1 = MOB([50, 50])
    Mob2 = MOB([100, 300])
    mobs.add(Mob1, Mob2)
```

Now two new mobs will respawn in the listed coordinates, but only one stays visable and does what its supposed to. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It's not possible to tell without seeing the entire code. As I already said in another comment, you probably use the `Mob` variable all over the place when in fact you should use the items of the `mobs` group. I think you should ask a seperate question and post your full code, at least the parts where you use the `Mob` variable.

Comment: I did @DominicKexel listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551395/managing-groups-in-pygame

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`kill()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) on a [`Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) is enough to remove it from its [`Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.groups). If you want to create two more [`Sprites`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), you have to create two instances and also add both of them to your [`Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

```
if Mob.hp == 0:
    # remove the old mob from the group
    Mob.kill() 

    # create two new ones
    m1, m2 = MOB([50, 50]), MOB([51, 50]) 

    # add both to the group
    mobs.add(m1, m2)
```

(I assume `Mob` is an instance of `MOB`, which is a subclass of [`Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite); and `mobs` is a [`Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).)

Comment: Would I have two define    new_mob1 and    new_mob2 as separate variables

Comment: sorry, had a typo. It should be just `m1` and `m2`. You could just inline the variables: `mobs.add(MOB([50, 50]), MOB([51, 50]) )` if you want to or use a collection: `new_mobs = MOB([50, 50]), MOB([51, 50])` `mobs.add(*new_mobs)`. It's up to you.

Comment: when ever I run your code, the two mobs just stay in the same place, they don't chase the Player like they are supposed to. Also, this has to happen every time I kill a Mob, so eventually mobs will be all on the screen.

Comment: @user2564732 You asked about removing a sprite from a group and adding new ones. Nobody knows how the rest of your code looks like. I can only assume that you use the `Mob` variable to implement the *chase the Player*-feature. If this is the case, you should loop over the sprites in the `mob` group instead of using a single variable `Mob`.

Comment: Might I say, when ever I hit the first one, it disappears, and the other two appear, but when I hit it in the same place, it re-appears, and the other two disappear. Why?