# Managing Groups in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game where when you kill one mob, two more appears. I have it so when you kill one mob, the two others appear, but only one stays visible and behaves like its supposed to. The other just appears then disappears. How can I get it so both of them behave the way they are supposed to. Here is what I have so far:

[MOB Class]

```
class MOB(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.image = ENEMY
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
        self.rect.right, self.rect.bottom = location
        self.rect.center = location
        self.speed = random
        self.hp = 4
    def update(self):
         if self.hp == 0:
            mobs.add(self)
            self.image = ENEMY
            self.pos = [0,0]
            self.hp = 4
    def moveH(self):
        if self.rect.centerx >= Player.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.left = self.rect.left - 4
        elif self.rect.centerx <= Player.rect.centerx:
            self.rect.left = self.rect.left + 4

        def moveV(self):
        if self.rect.centery <= Player.rect.centery:
            self.rect.top = self.rect.top + 4
        if self.rect.centery >= Player.rect.centery:
            self.rect.top = self.rect.top - 4
```

[Adding and Removing in main loop]

```
for Mob in mobs:
    if Mob.hp == 0:
        score = score + 1
        Mob.kill()
        new_mobs = MOB([50, 50]), MOB([60, 300])
        mobs.add(*new_mobs)
```

[Redrawing and moving in main loop]

```
for Mob in mobs:
    Mob.moveV()
    Mob.moveH()
    screen.blit(Mob.image, Mob.rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mobs.remove(Mob) instead Mob.kill
it might work :D

Comment: Kill will cause that one to die, and, ensures it doesn't have any references in any spriteGroups

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is erasing the Rect's width and height. If you want to use coordinates of the center, use:

   ```
   self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
   self.rect.center = location
   ```
2. What is `mobs.add()` in `update()`? Because update is normally called every frame, and I'm guessing mobs is a sprite group.
3. Your update:

   for Mob in mobs:
       Mob.moveV()
       Mob.moveH()
       screen.blit(Mob.image, Mob.rect)

should be

```
mobs.update()
mobs.draw(screen)
```

Check out this guys example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418347/341744

Comment: Could you post a little bit more. When I change it based off your answer, the two mobs stay in place at the two spawn points, and the score counter (not listed) keeps going up, saying I killed a bunch of mobs

Comment: Also, the one sprite i killed only disappears, but according to the game, his is still there, but invisible

Comment: okay now, the two appear, and the one I killed is gone for good, but now the two that show up, only move within a invisible window